# django - default value name for the ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model for uploading photos in an album by the users. But if the user don't want to create an album, and just upload photos, I want it to be uploaded in a default album, namely 'Default album'. So that, whenever the user uploads photo without creating a new album, the 'Default album should be updated by that photos. For that, I thought about giving a `default value` in the title of the Album, but I also don't want to create a new album with name 'Default album' whenever the user doesn't create a new album to upload photo. I just want to update the 'Default Album'. Please suggest me how to achieve the above mentioned. And also is it okay to just give the `ForeignKey field` of the User to the Album class and not the Photo class??? Thank you!

models.py:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


class Photo(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, use the [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default) option, it's straight from the docs and make the album always default to "Default Album" since it's not the relationship that should have the name but the actual model it references.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="Default Album")
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about doing so, but won't it create a new album with that name? Or will the 'Default Album' be updated each time a user uploads a photo without creating an album?

Comment: It will always default to that name when an album is created yes (unless it's supplied). And unless a user changes name of default album then it's always there/updated to "Default Album".

Comment: Ok. And what if the user creates an album with the name 'Default Album'? Will they clash? Or will it be updated in the 'Default Album' and not create new one?

Comment: If he creates an album with "Default Album" then depending on how you've set it up YOU can either just default him to the new one or rename it to "Default Album (1)". This isn't the responsibility of Django but rather you as the application programmer. If you create one with the same name as the default value, Django won't care. The default value is there for you incase you forget to supply a value.

Comment: Ok, so can I can restrict the user not to name it 'Default Album' in the models and not in the forms? And please correct me, whether the Foreignkey for user in the Album is sufficient for that? Or do I have to make a field for User in the Photo class too? I am sorry, I am asking too much question, I am just a learner! :)

Comment: Yes, of course. In the `save()` of your model you can do anything!